# CSS: nested ol start numbering at 1.1

Tags: css, nested, css-counter

I have a nested set of related topics/subtopics, using `<ol>`.  The CSS I have so far works great from the top of the tree, but users are able to click on subtopics, and I'm redrawing the nested set of `<ol>`, starting from where the user clicked. My problem is, I need to respect the chapter numbers, etc.

So, if a typical structure might be this:

```
Vehicles
  1. Automobile
    1.1 Street
      1.1.1 Sedan
      1.1.2 Coup
      1.1.3 Truck
    1.2 Race
      1.2.1 
  2. Rail
    2.1 Locomotive
    2.2 High Speed
    2.3 Uni
```

And the user clicks on `1.1 Street`, I need to show:

```
1.1 Street
  1.1.1 Sedan
  1.1.2 Coup
  1.1.3 Truck
```

The CSS I have so far is this:

```
ol li {display:block;}
ol > li:first-child {counter-reset: item;}
ol > li {counter-increment: item; position: relative;}
ol > li:before {content:counters(item, ".") ". "; position: absolute; margin-right: 100%; right: 10px;}
```

I've tried a few variations with a second counter, but no dice! Complicating this problem, the tree can be infinitely deep, so any hard coded solution is out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your list in an outer `<ol><li>` block, then update your CSS to show the counter for the nested content

```
ol ol > li:before {content:counters(item, ".") ". "; position: absolute; margin-right: 100%; right: 10px;}
```

Here's a demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/q34wdw5p/

Comment: Yah man! @Anthony E, that did the trick!  Thanks for sharing your stardom!  I"ll have to play with it a bit, the nested `<ol>` is generated, and placed in the DOM by Meteor's Blaze templating, so there's a bit on a timing issue.  It's probable given my need that I'll have to forego Blaze, and manually recursively build the nested `<ol>`. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, got it! Easier than I thought: Using the @Anthony suggestion, I figured out a solution, I did have to uniquely identify the set of nested `<ol>`, and Meteor jockies might know what I'm talking about here - multiple templates of the same type in the DOM at once.